# Scala.js compilation error object Promise does not take type parameters

Tags: promise, scala.js

Try to get a future from a callback example running, using the code in
[Scala.js documentation](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/sjs-for-js/es6-to-scala-part3.html):

```
def onLoadFuture(img: HTMLImageElement) = {
  if (img.complete) {
    Future.successful(img.src)
  } else {
    val p = Promise[String]()
// [error]          ^
    img.onload = { (e: Event) =>
      p.success(img.src)
    }
    p.future
  }
}
```

get compilation error: object Promise does not take type parameters

plugins.sbt:

```
 addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.23")
```

build.sbt:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("client")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
  addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full),
  scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := false,
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.thoughtworks.binding" %%% "dom" % "latest.release",
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.3",
    "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.6.7"
  )
).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin).enablePlugins(JSDependenciesPlugin).
  dependsOn(sharedJs)
```

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: First I add import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Promise }  and I get duplicate Promise ... so I  commented it out, then I changed the sequence of imports as follows:  
`import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Promise }
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}    

import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.runNow
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation._
import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.global
import scala.scalajs.js._
import scala.scalajs._
import scalajs.jsmessages._` now it seems to work ...

Comment: Typically you don't import `scala.scalajs.js._` but import `scala.scalajs.js` and write out the `js` to make it clear that you are writing about a JS type.

Comment: Thanks for the hint/question. Now it seems to me that the order of import statements is important ...

Comment: Order is sometimes important, yes, but really -- it's kind of dangerous to import `scala.scalajs.js._`, precisely because you can accidentally import things like the incompatible JavaScript Promise type.  It's best to just not do the import that way...